# solving algebraic equations of degree greater than 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I observed that the roots of a quadratic equation can easily be found by multiplying the equation throughout by 4a (a being the coefficient of x squared) and "completing the square".So I tried to follow a similar method for the cubic but failed to find a corresponding multiplying factor to complete the cube. Is there one at all? What about equations of higher degrees?Would anyone kindly explain the theory behind this in detail?

Comment: You can't simply complete the cube, but there is a cubic formula obtained by some messier manipulations. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula. For degree 4 see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html. For degree 5 and up you can't do this using only radicals! The reason why lies in Galois theory, which you can find in most undergrad algebra textbooks (like Artin's Algebra).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for helping! In fact that is the point I am trying to convince myself about.I mean,why can't we simply complete the cube and the quartic (Let aside the higher degree) Iike the quadratic ? Is there any particular point I am not getting?

Comment: For most cubics, there does not exist a substitution that will transform it into the form $(x-a)^3 = b$, which is what you would need to "complete the cube". Galois theory provides a deep reason for this: polynomials have associated symmetry groups, called Galois groups, which capture how the roots relate to each other algebraically. For quadratics, every polynomial has the same Galois group. But for cubics (and higher degree), you can only complete the cube if you have a particularly simple Galois group.

Comment: Thanks a ton sir!

Comment: In general, there are difficult formulas for cubic and quartic equations.  Galois (?) proved that there is none for higher order polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a general answer is provided by Galois theory, it's not especially difficult to see why computing the cube doesn't always work. First, we can informally observe that a quadratic can be written as $x^2 + a x + b$, which has two 'degrees of freedom'. The expression $(x-c)^2 + d$ that we aim to write it as also has two degrees of freedom, so it is not especially surprising that we can match coefficients. On the other hand, a cubic is written as $x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c$, and we aim to write it as $(x-d)^3 + e$. But there aren't enough degrees of freedom in this expression for it to be generally possible.

Let's look at a specific example now. Suppose we'd like to write $x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 1$ in the form $(x-d)^3 + e$, i.e. complete the cube. But $(x-d)^3 + e = x^3 - 3dx^2 + 3d^2 x - d^3 + e$, so it looks like we'd need to have
$$-3d =3 \qquad 3d^2=2 \qquad -d^3+e=1$$
since the expressions need to be equal for all values of $x$.
Looking at the first expression, $d=-1$. But this contradicts the second equation, because it would give $3 = 2$. For contrast with the quadratic case, in that case there would be only two equations to solve with two unknowns, which can be done. So, completing the cube is not in general possible.

Finally I'd recommend reading up on Cardano's method if you're interested in solving cubics, it's very possible to understand without any Galois theory.